# App crashes when including AppCompatTextView in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I'm having trouble including an `Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView` element in a layout in my Android app.

(I need the AppCompat version to get auto-sizing text on versions pre-API26)

My `AppCompatTextView` is defined as follows:

```
    <Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/each_pays_amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/decimal_zeroes"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="140sp"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And I have the following in my `app.iml` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:1.0.1'
}
```

The app compiles and runs OK, but as soon as the `Activity` that includes the `layout` with the `AppCompatTextView` loads the app crashes with the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.nooriginalthought.yabs, PID: 8640
              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: 
              Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView" on path: D...
```

So it looks like the support library is not being included for some reason, or at least the `AppCompatTexView` is not being found in the support library that I am including.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an incorrect View name. You're using:

```
<Android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView>

   ...

 />
```

it should be start with lowercase:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

   ...

 />
```

Comment: Ah, thanks.. such a stupid mistake. (Though I would have expected lint to have picked that up as an error)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AndroidX and you have this problem you can replace

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
```

to

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
```